# java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am new at fragments. ı made a simple fragment but couldn't manage to work without crash...**When ı press buttons for to start fragments it is crashing**... I am lookig for good fragment learning sources and waiting your advices..
Thanks for your interest...
Here is the main activity;

```
package com.example.fragments;


import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Main extends Activity {

    MediaPlayer sound;
    Button black,red,blue;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        sound = MediaPlayer.create(Main.this, R.raw.alkis);
        black=(Button)findViewById(R.id.colorBlack);
        red=(Button)findViewById(R.id.colorRed);
        blue=(Button)findViewById(R.id.colorBlue);

        black.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
                sound.start();
                FragmentTransaction transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
                         transaction.add(R.id.colorBlack, new FragmentAferin());

                         transaction.commit();


            }
        });
        red.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
                sound.start();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
                transaction.add(R.id.colorRed, new FragmentAferin());

                transaction.commit(); 

            }
        });
        blue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
                sound.start();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
                transaction.add(R.id.colorBlue, new FragmentAferin());

                transaction.commit(); 

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

and here is the main XML Layout;

```
   <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         tools:context=".Main" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/colorBlack"
        style="@style/FragmentTextTheme"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="@string/black"
        android:text="@string/black"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/colorRed"
        style="@style/FragmentTextTheme"
        android:background="@color/Red"
        android:text="@string/red" 
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/colorBlue"
        style="@style/FragmentTextTheme"
        android:background="@color/Blue"
        android:text="@string/blue" 
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

and here is the fragment class code;

```
package com.example.fragments;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public class FragmentAferin extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_aferin,
                container, false);

        return view;
    }
```

and here is the fragment XML layout;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/aferin"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

exception

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:875)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:441)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

thank you for your helps...

Comment: Try cleaning your project

Comment: ı did it but still same exception...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to add a fragment to your Buttons which does not work, because as the Exception says, Buttons aren't ViewGroups, so that can't have other Views inside.
So the exceptions are caused by the R.id.colorBlack - the ID here should be the ID of a ViewGroup, e.g. a LinearLayout

```
 FragmentTransaction transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
                     transaction.add(R.id.colorBlack, new FragmentAferin());

                     transaction.commit();
```

Where do you want your `FragmentAferin` to be placed?

Answer (score 0):

You class should extend `FragmentActivity` and not `Activity`

You can get this class from [Android support library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html)

Comment: ı did it but still crashs when ı pressed buttons